# A2P SMS gateway

Tags: sms, gateway, sms-gateway

I already have a SIM card with a company that allows tethering and A2P.

I want to be able to send an SMS with a unique sender ID (company name) using that sim card.

Is this possible and if so, what should I purchase and how do I set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is NOT possible to alter the senderid when sending SMS using a SIM card + modem. The senderid will simply be the number belonging to that SIM.

If you want to have a custom (alpha) senderid, your only option is using a professional A2P [SMS gateway](https://www.budgetsms.net). But even then it is not always possible, as not all countries allow alpha senderids. They might get overwritten to a short/longcode, or the operators require senderid whitelisting (basically, you need to request "access" to an alpha senderid, by sending your personal/company details and SMS content details to the operators. This is done to battle SPAM messages)

Comment: It would only be in the UK region which allows such. My carrier allows A2P and this was possible and works fine with a 4G dongle and R-Pi.

Comment: But I cannot see how you can use alpha senderid with such a setup.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention in my comment I got rid of the sender ID. It works fine but a custom sender ID wasn't possible using regular P2P SIM cards. I have accepted your answer for future viewers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is possible.

Most of the time you don't need any SIM card as you'll be using some sort of API, most of the time a HTTPS/JSON or HTTPS/XML API. If you intend to use a SIM to send SMSes, having a dedicated sender ID will be most probably impossible: using a SIM will make your request arrive through the "regular" signaling link just as "any subscriber" that sends an SMS from his mobile, while using an API will make you use the SMPP links to the SMS-C where specific configuration can be done on per client basis. If I misunderstood something, please sent a comment.

Anyway, you have to have an agreement with your SMS API provider or telco to use a dedicated ID